# "baking in the freezer" in Heinrich Böll

Tags: translation

I recently read Heinrich Böll's =The Clown= (in English) and stumbled over a passage that appeared to be an inelegant translation.  Our narrator is describing making props out of ice for an act in which they will melt away during the performance.  He proposes to "bake" them in the refrigerator.  Which I took to mean "freeze" in a freezer.

But it looks like "bake" is in the Böll.

I'd like to try to understand if "baking" water into ice in a freezer is idiomatic German, or if Böll is trying to communicate something else with that odd choice of words.

Here's the passage in German:

> Ich dachte auch an meine Schlüsselpantomime. Ich konnte mir Plastilin
> besorgen, einen Schlüssel hineindrücken, Wasser in die Hohlform gießen
> und im Eisschrank ein paar Schlüssel backen; es war sicher möglich,
> eine kleine transportable Kühltruhe zu finden, in der ich mir jeden
> Abend für meinen Auftritt die Schlüssel backen würde, die während der
> Nummer dahinschmelzen sollten.

Comment: Remember, the guy saying this is a clown ;)

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes in a colloquial context "backen" is used in a very broad sense to mean "to create coarsly from small-grained material" or "create in a make-shift way with smaller constituent parts". In this sense you can "bake keys by freezing water in an appropriately-shaped mold". But also to the German ear (at least mine) this sounds strange - but that is in these situation often wanted for the pun or the slightly derogative connotation when used outside the real baking context.

Similarily you bake cake in the sand pit as kid etc. (though here it is usually not derogative "Sandkuchen backen").

A near analogon at the same "level" which involves more mechanical work than glue-ish work implied by 'backen' is "zusammenschustern".

Comment: Also: to create the ideal match from nothing, e.g. *sich einen Mann backen*

Comment: English has some colloquial expressions involving baking as well, for example you a say a woman "has a bun in the oven". English Wiktionary doesn't mention this meaning at all, but the German one lists some related examples: *Den idealen Ehepartner muss man sich schon selber backen.* (This is basically Janka's comment.) *Der frisch gebackene Leutnant ging an Bord der Fregatte.* *Meinst du, du kriegst die Hausaufgaben selber gebacken, oder soll ich dir helfen?*

Answer (score 4):

What Böll describes as

> Plastilin besorgen, einen Schlüssel hineindrücken, Wasser in die Hohlform gießen

reminds me of producing a baking mold for [Speculaas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speculaas) ("Spekulatius") and filling it with dough.

[image]

Then the association with baking is not far away. Perhaps this is why Böll writes

> im Eisschrank ein paar Schlüssel backen.

Okay, this is just a <del>Spekulatius</del>  speculation.

Anyway, have a look at Böll's short story "[Nicht nur zur Weihnachtszeit](http://kulturkirchen.org/texte/events/Entdeckungen/Belletristik%20%C2%B7%20Heinrich%20B%C3%B6ll:%20Nicht%20nur%20zur%20Weihnachtszeit)" from 1952 in which Speculaas plays a vital role.

There is a stage play "[Spekulatius & Essiggurken](https://www.nd-aktuell.de/artikel/691506.b-oell-urauffuehrung.html)" which is based on Böll's text.

Answer (score 3):

Laut [Deutschem-Wörterbuchnetz](https://woerterbuchnetz.de/?sigle=DWB&lemid=B00080#0) ist die Gemeinsamkeit das krustenbildende Erstarren, welches im Backofen wie im Eisfach stattfindet, und war früher wohl ein gängiger Ausdruck.

> 2. zumal kleben, haften, starren, frieren, ganz wie παγῆναι: auch
>    braucht er (gott) der sonnen nicht dazu (zum aufthauen), sondern es
>    flegt nach der sonnen deste herter zu backen. Luther 5, 469b;

Mir war dieser Sprachgebrauch jedoch nicht bewusst.

Answer (score 2):

"Backen" - in the sense of letting set. Whether the apparent oxymoron of baking is intentional when used for letting something set or harden in a freezer cannot be determined. Usually, but not always, we "bake" in an oven, but we use backen in a broader sense for creating something with ingredients outside an oven and then for actually baking that new mixture in the oven to set to a new consistency. Good other example, as mentioned by another contributor, is Sandformen backen in the sandbox, done by children when playing pretend-baking like they have seen in the kitchen. Being a native German speaker, I wouldn't have pondered too long over the use of "baking in the freezer" in Böll's sentence in question.